# For MySQL, why the following two sqls both work fine?

Tags: mysql, sql

The sqls are as follows:

```
select T1.a from T1 where T1.b in (select T2.b from T2 where T2.b = 'b' and T1.c = 'c')
```

```sql
select T1.a from T1 where T1.b in (select T2.b from T2 where T2.b = 'b') and T1.c = 'c'
```

Comment: are you sure they work? the first one should not run afaik.

Comment: I think in first query there is a typo mistake of "and" instead of "where" in subquery.

Comment: Most likely the optimizer realizes in the first case that `T1.c = 'c'` is not depending on the values in `T2`. The query then becomes equivalent to the second case.

Comment: The sqls are updated, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The first is:

```
select T1.a
from T1
where T1.b in (select T2.b from T2 and T1.c = 'c')
```

The reference to `T1` is to the outer query.  This is allowed.  In fact, it is needed for correlated subqueries, an important part of the SQL language.

In this case, though, the second version is much preferable.  The filtering logic is much easier to understand when it is directly on the table in the `from`.

Comment: But why can he put an `and` after a `from` statement?

Comment: @Praind he has a `where` after the `from`

Comment: Oh now he has. Not at the time I posted the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The second condition refering to table `T1` which is reference in outer query. So your both query get executed. You can also achieve your result like this

```
select T1.a from T1 where T1.c = 'c' and T1.b in (select T2.b from T2 and )
```

Your second condition is always refrenced to `T1` so its place doesn't matter in your queries.